# Xamarin error: Cannot implicitly convert type 'MasterDetail.G2.Main' to 'Xamarin.Forms.Page'

Tags: c#, xamarin

When I try to change the main page it gives me the error even when I use navigation page.

Should I use `as` to change the type to portable type? What is the best practice?

> error:Severity Error   CS0029  Cannot implicitly convert type 'MasterDetail.G2.Main' to 'Xamarin.Forms.Page'

```
Main.xaml.cs
    using System;
            using System.Collections.Generic;
            using System.Linq;
            using System.Text;
            using System.Threading.Tasks;
            
            using Xamarin.Forms;
            using Xamarin.Forms.Xaml;
            
            namespace MasterDetail.G2
            {
                [XamlCompilation(XamlCompilationOptions.Compile)]
                public partial class Main : ContentView
                {
                    public Main()
                    {
                        InitializeComponent();
                    }
                }
            }


app.xaml.cs
using MasterDetail.G2;
using System;
using Xamarin.Forms;
using Xamarin.Forms.Xaml;

namespace MasterDetail
{
    public partial class App : Application
    {
        public App()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            MainPage = new Main();
        }

        protected override void OnStart()
        {
        }

        protected override void OnSleep()
        {
        }

        protected override void OnResume()
        {
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

change

```
public partial class Main : ContentView
```

to

```
public partial class Main : ContentPage
```

Comment: You will also need to modify your XAML to use the correct type

Answer (score 0):

It is not certain what you want to do, but you can't cast some class to another class that doesn't inherit from it. `ContentPage` doesn't inherit from `ContentView` or your `Main` class.

Answer (score 0):

change the derived class from **ContentView** to **ContentPage**

on Main.xaml, change  to

Comment: *** on Main.xaml, change it to <ContentPage>< / ContentPage> instead of contentview